# What do we do with this non-starter question?

Tags: discussion, specific-question

[Pathfinder explosive runes abuse](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/q/82481/1204) describes a scenario and the asker (presumably the GM) is unhappy with it, and says:

> I don't like this in the least bit but I am not sure how can I argue that it won't work.

Well... it *will* work if things go as described, and they're well aware of it, so I'm not sure how we can help. And, well, if they have problems with someone wanting to "use pathfinder's explosive runes as an offensive spell" (considering it *is* one) I'm not sure what we can really do for them.

... what do we do with this question? I'm at a loss here.

Answer (score 4):

We can probably solve the situation they describe, even if the solution isn't what they desire. The answers would be competing first on the most useful problem to identify, and second on the best solution for that problem.

The breakdown of potential problems I see there is:

1. The spell being used offensively
2. The asker not liking it

Personally I think the real problem is (2) and we'll see good answers competing to solve their *"I don't like it!"* problem. However, there's also room for an answer to come along and show a hitch in using the spell that way that might entirely prevent, or just prevent the worst of, this "abuse". An answer might even tackle both angles.

I don't think there's much really to be done with the question otherwise. It's fairly clear, topical, not too broad, and doesn't solicit or require opinions. It's not really ever going to be useful for anyone else, so a downvote could be easily justified.

Comment: I think the core of the question is actually "*Why* does OP not like it?", combined with "Why would the sorceror and paladin think it's a good idea in the first place?" ShadowKras answer is quite clear in showing that it's not.

Comment: @MrLemon I don't think I understand. Those are both questions that could be asked in comments to help clarify the question, yes, but they don't sound like anything the question post itself would ask?